# Is there a way to sign an MSI file so that Norton Internet Security recognizes it?

Tags: code-signing, antivirus, norton

Norton Internet Security doesn't recognize my MSI file as being signed. It is signed and with a certificate issued by Comodo. IE9's SmartScreen filter recognizes it as being signed but Norton File Insight simply says "unavailable." I think this is a bug on Norton's part but until they fix it, I would rather not have my MSI flagged as a possible threat.

I can't seem to get past Symantec's tech support's auto emails to resolve this and whitelisting the file is no good because as soon as I post an update it's back to square one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems that the bug is with Norton File Insight. It's unable to check MSI files for digital certificates.  You can read about in the Symantec forum here: http://community.norton.com/t5/Norton-Internet-Security-Norton/Bug-with-File-Insight-not-detecting-digital-signature/m-p/491390/highlight/false#M164254. One of the staff members finally admitted that this is an issue that will be fixed in 2012.

But, come on, detecting a digital certificate is not exactly difficult and it's such a basic part of checking for malware. Malware is rarely digitally signed and in the rare case it's signed, it is never digitally signed with a certificate from a trusted authority unless it has been compromised. IE9 recognizes these facts and acts accordingly.

Symantec has had notice of this bug for at least two years and it must be easy to patch. But the problem continues.

Answer (score 0):

We seem to have the same problem. Our software is signed and accepted by IE's SmartScreen no problem. However, we're now getting reports that our downloads are tossed out by Norton 360.

So, while we're investigating, just like to stay in the loop to see if there is any progress reported in this thread.

Will update is we have anything to report......

Comment: Symantec technical support finally called me back (after a few rounds of auto-generated emails telling me that the best way to avoid false positives is to sign my application with a trusted authority).  The person I spoke with said he understood the problem was that the signature was not being recognized and that I had to register my website with Norton Web Safe. I said it sounded absurded , but he insisted that the verification with Norton is tied to the web site the file originated from.

Comment: So, I dutifully registered with Norton Web Safe and got the same result. And of course I did - whether or not a website is safe says nothing on whether a file is safe. And it certainly doesn't explain why digital signatures are not recognized as even existing.

Comment: So, back to square one. I'll call Symantec back and get the excuse of the day.

Comment: I've been on the phone with Symantec. The customer support is actually pretty good. They keep calling me back as they look into the problem. The team doesn't seem to know why this problem is occurring and they are now going to the developer team themselves to get an answer.